# how to fix - stageResult set to FAILURE but still get success in jenkins

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, stage

I'm trying to create a very simple pipeline,
it has one stage and one step.

it uses the job 'build' I created as freestyle (which works) but I added an error (the parameter project name has a wrong value - 'test3' instead of 'test')

when I ran it, it stay green and send "success" although it failed - if I enter the log I'll see this:

```
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\pipeline testing
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (1)
[Pipeline] catchError
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] build (Building build)
Scheduling project: build
Starting building: build #62
[Pipeline] }
ERROR: build #62 completed with status FAILURE (propagate: false to ignore)
[Pipeline] // catchError
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

I tried using the new plugin:
catchError(buildResult: 'SUCCESS', stageResult: 'FAILURE')

which as I understand is suppose to send "FAILURE" for stage and "SUCCESS" for the build as a whole.

the stageResult doesn't work for me.

I tried adding "propagate: true" for the "build job:"
but it didn't help either.
this is the pipeline itself:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages 
    {
        stage('1') 
        {
            steps 
            {
                catchError(buildResult: 'SUCCESS', stageResult: 'FAILURE')
                {
                    build job: 'build',parameters: [string(name: 'Project_Name', value: 'test3'), 
                    string(name: 'Environment_Name', value: 'Dev_Env_1')]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is a really "on the point" feature for what I need but it refuses to work.
Instead of getting a failure and continuing with the project I get success each time.

It does continue (if I have more stages) but the issue is that I need it to be red and tell me the stage failed instead of green with success.

I did updated my jenkins version to 2.192 
pipeline groovy is 2.74
and "pipeline: basic steps" plugin to 2.18

EDIT: the solution in the end was to update all the rest of the plugins

Comment: Does it happen every time?

Comment: yes, I tried it many times with different cases - same result

Comment: What version of [Pipeline Groovy](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Groovy+Plugin) plugin do have installed?

Comment: pipeline groovy - 2.74, I'll add it to the post

Comment: I am _not_ using the Jenkins _weekly_ release rather the LTS version `2.176.3` with `Pipeline: Groovy` version `2.74` and `Pipeline: Basic Steps` version `2.18`. It's working fine for me. If possible, you may give it a shot with the LTS one.

Comment: I'm downloading it right now, but I don't think it should be different from the weekly update

Comment: I am also little skeptical whether anything will change but doesn't harm to give it a try given the fact that it's working for me. Moreover, it will be easier to debug further if we have identical configuration.

Comment: I'm here with it, still doesn't work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198860/discussion-between-technext-and-jhon-smith).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides having following versions of plugins, seems (as discussed on chat) there were other plugins as well which had to be updated.

```
Pipeline Basic Steps: 2.18
Pipeline: Groovy version 2.74
Pipeline: Basic Steps version 2.18
```

After updating all the plugins in Plugins section's (`http://<JENKINS_HOME>/pluginManager/`) `Updates` tab, issue got resolved.

Comment: This issue also also indicate you need a core version of at least 2.164.3.
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-57826
I can definitely say that 2.164.2 did not work for me, but 2.176.3 does.